# FOS is giving confusing impression when printing roles

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

Output below gives me a wrong impression. Can someone explain why I'm getting result below and not others I mentioned at the bottom since they make more sense to me?

Thanks in advance

NOTE: I am logged in as `superadmin`

**TWIG LOOP:**

```
{% for role in app.user.roles %}
    {{ role }}
    {% if not loop.last %}
        <br />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**TWIG OUTPUT:**

```
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN 
ROLE_USER
```

**security.yml:**

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

**What I have in role field in database for superadmin account:**

```
a:1:{i:0;s:16:"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN";}
```

**I WOULD EXPECT TO SEE ONE OF THESE AS AN OUTPUT:**

- `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` (which is stored in database against my account)
- `ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH` (set against my role in security.yml)

Comment: Is your problem that you are seeing `ROLE_USER` too? Every user has the default role `ROLE_USER` added to it by default when you `getRoles` using the `FOSUserBundle` (and also ignored when you try to add it using `addRole`). It will never show up on the database as it is never actually added to the model.

Comment: @Qoop - You're right. I discovered it yesterday and decided to write code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My users were confused and gave me a bit of head ache so I had to do this to avoid such misunderstand:

Since the ROLE_USER is added to the end of the array, I excluded it.

```
{% for role in app.user.roles | slice(0, (app.user.roles | length) - 1) %}
    {{ role }}
    {% if not loop.last %}
        ,
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to do it yourself, as there is no built-in mecanics to do this (and this is not because of FosUserBundle)

You may use the `security.role_hierarchy.roles` container parameter to retrieve your configuration, and create a method that may display what you need (creating a Twig filter/function for example).